# Why are all data types returned as strings with sqlite3 fetchAll(PDO:FETCH_ASSOC) with PHP?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I am using

```
$rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

to get all the rows of my table.

The schema is defined as "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, year INTEGER, price REAL"

A row from he results of the fetchAll is

```
array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "The Dark Night"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "2008"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "19.95"
  }
```

Why are all the data types being returned as strings?  I want them to be returned as defined in the schema.  I understand the 'typeless' nature of SQLite, but they do define the limited data types as TEXT, INTEGER, and REAL.  How can I get the data to be returned with the specified data types?  I don't want to iterate through each row, and convert it with PHP - that just seems to be too slow.

The Complete Test Code as Follows:

```
<?
class sqlite_test {
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbase_filename = "test.sqlite";
        $this->init_dbase();

    }

    function init_dbase()
    {
        $this->pdo = new PDO("sqlite:".$this->dbase_filename);
    }

    function open_table()
    {
        $table = "dvds";

        if ( ! ($test_to_see_if_table_exists = $this->pdo->query("SELECT 1 from $table")) ) {
            $schema = "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, year INTEGER, price REAL";
            $query = "CREATE TABLE $table ($schema)";

            $this->pdo->exec($query);
        }

        return $test_to_see_if_table_exists;
    }

    function add_test_records()
    {
        $query[]='INSERT INTO dvds (id, title, year, price) VALUES (null, "The Dark Night", 2008, 19.95)';
        $query[]='INSERT INTO dvds (id, title, year, price) VALUES (null, "The Wizard of Oz", 1939, 9.95)';
        $query[]='INSERT INTO dvds (id, title, year, price) VALUES (null, "Jaws", 1977, 6.95)';

        $this->pdo->exec( join(';', $query) );
    }

    function dump_test_records()
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM dvds";

        if ($statement = $this->pdo->prepare($query)) {
            $statement->execute();

            $rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($rows);
            echo "</pre>";
        }
    }

    function main()
    {
        if ( ! $this->open_table() ) {
            $this->add_test_records();
        }

        $this->dump_test_records();
    }
}

$test = new sqlite_test();
$test->main();
```

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with SQLite; all records will be returned as collections of strings no matter what you use to query a database. It's just the nature of the database adapters/drivers used by PHP.

If you want the values to be of your desired types, you have to cast manually.

Comment: I have to say, this is a really sad statement about the design of PDO. I've been working with Microsoft's PDO driver for SQL Server and it behaves in exactly the same way: all data types are returned as strings, and querying the various indices available via getColumnMeta invariably returns "string" as the datatype regardless of the datatype in the origin database.

Comment: This is true. But the native SQLITE3 driver is working different. Here you don't have to cast manually. The types are as they are stored in sqlite3. Like rowid=(int), text=(string) etc...

Comment: And how do we get a hosting service to switch out the sql driver to a native one? And YITH_ll would anyone design a driver that ignores datatypes? Or is it because PDO is actually some kind of primitive ORM?(I'm using MySQLi, though). Having found this same issue with MariaDB, I've discovered why my code that was converted to "strict ===" no longer works. Which is BS, IMHO.

Comment: And what about setting PDO attribute `ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES` to `false`? Does it work only for MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

PHP 8.1 started returning numbers instead of strings for INTEGER fields (sqlite pdo).

Comment: Really? So that API isn't just bad, it's also unstable. Need to look into alternatives to PDO. (I know, I should look for alternatives to PHP but it's not so easy.)